# Как получить свойство объекта в JS?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Объясните, почему в таком коде как:

```
obj = {
    x: 10,
    y: this.x + 20
}
```

`obj.x = 10`, а `obj.y = NaN`. Хотя, если написать так:

```
obj = {
    x: 10,
    y: 20,
    foo: function() {return this.x + this.y}
}
```

`obj.foo() = 30`.

Как мне присвоить полю объекта другое поле этого же самого объекта?

Comment: `obj = {x: 10}; obj.y = obj.x + 20;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случае `this` - это не `obj`, а во втором вы вызываете метод объекта `obj`

Касаемо первого случая, если данный фрагмент кода выполняется в глобальном контексте или в функции, то `this == window` (если это браузер конечно) или объект для которого вызывается метод если этот фрагмент находится в методе.

По поводу второго вопроса могу предложить следующее:

```
obj = {};
obj.x = 10;
obj.y = obj.x + 20;
```

**Добавлено:**
Еще к первому фрагменту. Посмотрите что будет если

```js
x = 15;
obj = {
    x: 10,
    y: this.x + 20
}
alert(obj.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Предпочтительное объявление, позволяющее манипулировать перечисляемостью и задавать get\set + ещё множество других свойств, которые можно легко отыскать в хелпе -

```
var object = {};

Object.defineProperties(object, {
    'x': {
        value: 10
    },
    'y': {
        value: 15
    },
    'foo': {
        value: function( ){
            return this.x + this.y;
        }
    }
});

console.log(object.foo( ) ); // 25
```

Comment: C каких это пор оно предпочтительнее?